# 'bytes' object has no attribute 'items' while using list

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Getting error in: items = [item for item in body.items()]

I just want to add multiple orderitems.

I don't know this loop will work after this error.

But atleast you will understand my requirement

I am giving following data:

```
[
    {
        "service_id": 1,
        "quantity": 2,
        "price": 20
    },
    {
        "service_id": 2,
        "quantity": 3,
        "price": 20
    },
    {
        "service_id": 3,
        "quantity": 4,
        "price": 20
    }
]
```

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@csrf_exempt
# class CreteOrderView(View):
def create_order(request, *args, **kwargs):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        now = datetime.date.today()
        order = Order.objects.create(date=now)
        order.save()
        orderid = order.id
        order_id = orderid
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        price = request.session.get('price')
        quantity = request.session.get('quantity')
        print('quantity ' + str(quantity))
        service_id = request.session.get('service_id')
        body = request.body
        items = [item for item in body.items()]
        for item in items:
            orderitemcreate= OrderItem.objects.create(order_id_id=order_id,
                                                    service_id_id=service_id,
                                                    quantity=quantity,
                                                    price=price)
            orderitemcreate.save()
        return Response({"Order_id":str(order.id),
                        "Order_date":str(order.date),
                        "OrderItems_id" :str(orderitemcreate.id),
                        "service_id" :str(orderitemcreate.service_id),
                        "quantity" :str(orderitemcreate.quantity),
                        "price":str(orderitemcreate.price)})
        
    else:
        order_qs = models.Order.objects.all().values_list()
        OrderItem_qs = models.OrderItem.objects.all().values_list()
        return Response({"Order":str(order_qs),"OrderItem":str(OrderItem_qs)})
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have

```
 data = json.loads(request.body)
```

so I think you should use:

```
items = [item for item in data]
```